# Alterar value de um select no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2, html-select

Estou fazendo um sistema, e tem uma parte dele que precisava de um `select`. Os nomes dentro do `select` estão sendo exibidos, mas os dados gravados no banco (mysql) são relativos ao campo 'id', e preciso que seja gravado os do campo 'nome' da tabela 'ops' no campo 'operacao' da tabela 'fichas'.

Relacionamentos:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Op' => array(
        'className' => 'Op',
        'foreignKey' => 'ficha_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'operacao',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Ficha' => array(
        'className' => 'Ficha',
        'foreignKey' => 'ficha_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'operacao',
        'order' => ''
```

Procurei e até agora não encontrei como alterar os 'values' gerado pelo CakePHP.

Estrutura das tabelas:
fichas: id, funcionario, ordem_servico, operacao, inicio, final, contagem, ops_id
ops: id, nome, sigla, ficha_id, operacao
(o campo 'operacao' em 'ops' tive que criar em função da relação entre as tabelas).

Comment: Lendo a documentação acredito que pode ser feito isso:

$options = array("one" => 'one', "two" => 'two);
$this->Form->select('Model.field', $options));

No indice do array você define o value que você deseja, espero que seja isso, nunca utilizei o cakephp

Answer (score 3):

Dentro do seu model ops, atribua a seguinte variável:

```
public $displayField = 'nome';
```

E o próprio cake vai ajustar para o select exibir os nomes corretamente...

Fonte: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield

**Update:**
É necessário efetuar os relacionamentos corretamente para o método `find()` buscar as associações a apresentá-las corretamente.

Para o Model buscar seus associados corretamente, também é necessário setar o nível de recursão da operação de busca através do atributo de models `$recursive`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Neste caso sugiro utilizar o nível 0, por padrão o cake utiliza -1.

**Obs: Quanto maior o nível de recursão, mais dados o cake vai trazer do bd, e consequentemente, mais lento o processo.**

Recursão para todos os Models, declarado no escopo da classe AppModel(Não recomendado):

```
public $recursive = 0;
```

Setando apenas no escopo do método(recomendado) que deseja a recursão, ou para o model Ficha, declarando no escopo da classe:

```
public $this->Ficha->recursive = 0;
```

Após definir a recursão desejada, você vai efetuar o find:

```
$resultado = $this->Ficha->find('all');
```

O find vai trazer para você além dos dados do model 'Ops', também os dados dos associados definidos como `$hasOne`, `$belongsTo`, `$hasMany` e `HABTM`.

Para exibir os resultados do método, passe a variável `resultado` para sua View:

```
$this->set(compact('resultado'));
```

ou

```
$this->set('resultado', $resultado);
```

Você vai obter um array indexado na sua view.

Para verificar a estrutura do array, faça um debug do array dentro da view, e mostrará todos os dados que o find trouxe, do model Ficha e do model Associado Op.

```
<?php
    pr($resultado);
```

A partir disto, você separa todos os campos, como estão exibidos no array, como neste exemplo:

```
echo $resultado['Op']['nome'];
```

Comment: Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, mas tá dando erro no campo que deveria ser mostrado: Notice (8): Undefined index: Op [APP/View/Fichas/index.ctp

Comment: Você fez o `pr($resultado)`? Ele mostra a estrutura do array, e aí você checa se os índices estão corretos, também remova os campos ´fields´ dentro dos relacionamentos, ele vai restringir a busca somente aos campos que você definir alí.

Comment: Você chegou a fazer o tutorial do cakephp? Ele aborda todas estas questões, fica mais fácil compreender como funciona a lógica do cakephp.

Comment: O campo operação (que é o problemático) continua aparecendo o id. Sobre o tutorial, cai meio que de paraquedas no cakephp e fiz o suficiente para começar a minha aplicação, já que meu prazo não é muito longo para finalizar

Comment: Posta na sua pergunta, a estrutura das tabelas, acho que está com problemas na modelagem também. O cakePHP é bem chato quanto a isto, precisa seguir as convenções, e se você não concluir o tutorial, é bem complicado de terminar esta aplicação.

Comment: Eu fiz o tutorial do blog, mas já tentando adaptar para a minha aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Opa, demorei porque tinha largado essa parte, mas voltei e consegui. Na verdade, minhas relações estavam invertidas, o que eu demorei pra entender.

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Ficha' => array(
        'className' => 'Ficha',
        'foreignKey' => 'operacao',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'operacao',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Op' => array(
        'className' => 'Op',
        'foreignKey' => 'operacao',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'nome',
        'valueField' => 'nome',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',

    )
);
```

E a view ficou:

```
<?php echo h($ficha['Op']['nome']); ?>
```

Alterei o campo 'forenigKey' para 'operacao', pois era o campo que me interessava ser exibido.
Na verdade, não alterei o valor do select, que continua sendo gravado no banco o campo 'id'. Porém, a saída na view mostra o nome da operação e era essa a informação que precisava.

Mas enfim, está resolvido e funcionando. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Que bom cara, o que houve com sua conta?

Comment: Você é o autor da pergunta? De qlqr forma, poderia explicar o que quis dizer com "as relações estavam invertidas"? Não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: Bom dia. Sendo mais claro sobre como resolvi, as minhas relações entre tabelas estavam invertidas.
public $hasOne = array(
  'Ficha' => array(
   'className' => 'Ficha',
   'foreignKey' => 'operacao',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => 'operacao',
   'order' => ''
  )
 );
public $belongsTo = array(
  'Op' => array(
   'className' => 'Op',
   'foreignKey' => 'operacao',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => 'nome',
                        'valueField' => 'nome',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   
  )
 );
e a view ficou:
<?php echo h($ficha['Op']['nome']); ?>

Comment: Aterei o campo 'forenigKey' para operação, pois era o campo que me interessava ser exibido.
Na verdade, não alterei o valor do select, que continua sendo gravado no banco o campo 'id'. Porém, a saída na view mostra o nome da operação e era essa a informação que precisava.
Sobre a minha conta, não sei o que aconteceu. A senha não entrava, solicitei para alterar e acredito que tenha sido criada uma conta nova.

Comment: Foi criada uma conta nova porque o seu outro usuário [não era registrado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463/o-que-significa-usu%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-registrado). Solicitei ao nosso gerente de comunidade que mescle suas duas contas ok?

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto